# Trouble installing libbitcoin-system library

Tags: bitcoin, secp256k1, bitcoinlib

I´m trying to follow along the book from Andreas Antonopolus (Mastering bitcoin) and I would want to do everything in the book, so Im stuck with this:

trying to install the [bitcoin explorer command line tool](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/blob/master/README.md), I realized that I needed to install the [libbitcoin-client library](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-client) which then made me realize I had to had installed the [libbitcoin-protocol library](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-protocol) which then made me realize that I had to had installed the [libbitcoin-system library](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-system) , which then requires Boost ( some c++ libraries ) and the [libbitcoin/secp256k1 library](https://github.com/libbitcoin/secp256k1) as well … long story short … I´m stuck at installing the libbitcoin-system library, because when I type the following command:

```
cloud76@system76:~/libbitcoin-system$ ./configure --with-boost=/usr/local/boost_1_77_0 --with-boost-libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

after a long list of everything is OK, I get this one:

```
configure: error: libsecp256k1 >= 0.1.0.19 is required but was not found.
```

Can anyone help me try to find out how do I tell the configure command to find the secp256k1 library?? I´m running everything from an ubuntu pc … Im sure I installed the secp256k1 library correctly using autotools … but I´m stuck with this …

Comment: I am also trying to download it, did you manage to install it?

Comment: Yes, I did. The problem apparently was that I was using a different user to install those libraries. I just followed the book’s instructions with the user I installed bitcoin core (and all of the C++ libraries that comes with that) and it worked just fine